# android delete file from internal storage having name like something

Tags: java, android, android-file

I want to delete an existing file into internal storage from my android application,I have this peace of code that delete a file named 'my_filename'

```
File dir = getFilesDir();
File file = new File(dir, "my_filename");
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

My question is how can I delete a file having name like something, example:

```
String fileNameLike='testfile';
File dir = getFilesDir();
File file = new File(dir, "%" + fileNameLike + "%");
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

So my code need to delete the file having name like : `testfile`

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void deleteFilesInSdcard(String dirPath,String delname) {
    File f = new File(dirPath+"/");
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    for(int position=0;position<files.length;position++)
    {                       
        if(files[position].isDirectory())
        {               
            deleteFilesInSdcard(files[position].getAbsoluteFile().toString(),delname);
        }
        else
        {
              int slash= files[position].getName().lastIndexOf("/");
              String fna=files[position].getName().substring(slash+1);

              Log.i("File name ext",fna);
              if(fna.toLowerCase().matches(".*"+delname+".*"))
              {
                  File delf = new File(files[position].getAbsoluteFile().toString());
                  delf.delete();
              }

             // Log.i("File name",files[position].getAbsoluteFile().toString());                
        }                           
    }
  }
```

now you call

```
   deleteFilesInSdcard("/sdcard","fileneedtodelte");
```

Comment: java? android? RegexFilter , FileUtils and TrueFileFilter cannot be resolved in my eclipse and no import to fix .

Comment: Okay... need to dowlonad common-io jar file and add to java build path, [http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonsio01jar.htm]

Comment: this does not work for android app, its only working for java app

Answer (score 0):

```
    String path =    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Download";

        File f = new File(path);        
        File file[] = f.listFiles();


            for (File f1 : file)
            {
               if (f1.isFile() && f1.getPath().endsWith(".apk")) { f1.delete(); }
            }
```

This code is working, i list all the files under Download file and its working.